# error ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm practicing a lab manual excercise in which I have to create 6 tables. Creation of 5 is
successful.

But one line is giving error

```
constraint GRADE_Designation_FK 
   FOREIGN KEY(Designation) References EMPLOYEE(Designation),
```

ERROR at line 7:

> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Queries of 2 linked tables are

```
create table EMPLOYEE
(
    Empno number(4) constraint EMPLOYEE_Empno_PK PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar2(10) not null,
    Designation varchar2(50),
    Qualification varchar2(10),
    Joindate date
);

create table GRADE
(
    Designation varchar2(50) constraint GRADE_Designation_PK PRIMARY KEY,
    Grade number(2),
    TotalPosts number(4),
    PostsAvailable number(4),

    constraint GRADE_Grade_CK  check(Grade between 1 and 20),
    constraint GRADE_PostsAvailable_CK check(PostsAvailable <= TotalPosts),
    constraint GRADE_Designation_FK FOREIGN KEY(Designation) References EMPLOYEE(Designation)
);
```

Tried

```
create table GRADE
(
    Designation varchar2(50) constraint GRADE_Designation_PK PRIMARY KEY,
    Grade number(2),
    TotalPosts number(4),
    PostsAvailable number(4),

    constraint GRADE_Grade_CK  check(Grade between 1 and 20),
    constraint GRADE_PostsAvailable_CK check(PostsAvailable <= TotalPosts)
);

create table EMPLOYEE
(
    Empno number(4) constraint EMPLOYEE_Empno_PK PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar2(10) not null,
    Designation varchar2(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Qualification varchar2(10),
    Joindate date default sysdate

    constraint EMPLOYEE_Designation_FK FOREIGN KEY(Designation) References GRADE(Designation),
);
```

Now new error

> constraint EMPLOYEE_Designation_FK FOREIGN KEY(Designation) References GRADE(Designation)
>      *
>
> ERROR at line 8:
>
> ORA-02253: constraint specification not allowed here

Comment: You need a comma after "Joindate date default sysdate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the constraint on the wrong table. You should create a foreign key on EMPLOYEE.DESIGNATION, referencing back to GRADE.DESIGNATION.

So your tables should look something like:

```
create table GRADE
(
Designation varchar2(50) constraint GRADE_Designation_PK PRIMARY KEY,
Grade number(2),
TotalPosts number(4),
PostsAvailable number(4),
constraint GRADE_Grade_CK  check(Grade between 1 and 20),
constraint GRADE_PostsAvailable_CK check(PostsAvailable <= TotalPosts),
);

create table EMPLOYEE
(
Empno number(4) constraint EMPLOYEE_Empno_PK PRIMARY KEY,
Name varchar2(10) not null,
Designation varchar2(50)
  constraint EMPLOYEE_FK1
    REFERENCES GRADE(DESIGNATION),
Qualification varchar2(10),
Joindate date
);
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: DESIGNATION is primary key in Grade Table.And tried unique constraint,still not working

Comment: I edited my answer to show how this should be done. The foreign key constraint should be on EMPLOYEE, referencing GRADE - you've got it the other way around. Best of luck.

Comment: edited my question...tried your method too.new error

Answer (score 1):

> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

That error is very self explanatory and tells you what's wrong. In your case, you are trying to create foreign key on a non primary key column and so the error

```
constraint GRADE_Designation_FK FOREIGN KEY(Designation) 
               References EMPLOYEE(Designation)
                                  <--Here
```

`Designation` in `EMPLOYEE` table is not a primary key and you can't create FK on a non primary key column. Your table creation rather should look like

```
create table GRADE
(
Designation varchar2(50) constraint GRADE_Designation_PK PRIMARY KEY,
employee_Empno number(4),
Grade number(2),
TotalPosts number(4),
PostsAvailable number(4),
constraint GRADE_Grade_CK  check(Grade between 1 and 20),
constraint GRADE_PostsAvailable_CK check(PostsAvailable <= TotalPosts),
constraint GRADE_Designation_FK FOREIGN KEY(employee_Empno) 
References EMPLOYEE(Empno));
```

Comment: i have to submit manual and i can not add column by my self.need to use which are provided in question.

Comment: I see your edit in question. That should do the work fine. You are getting that new error cause, you are missing a `,` before last line in `employee` table.

Answer (score 0):

It was the order of execution which has causes us this issue, make sure you have tables created with NOT NULL Enabled before adding those constraints to avoid this error.